Do we have an explanation for the windbag experiment?
I came across this Cool Science video and his description of it as an example of Bernoulli's Principle.
I am looking for an explanation using equations and math and physics. The question has been raised in other forums, but I can't find any answers.
[EDIT]
Since this question was closed, needing details or clarity, guidelines advise to be more specific about what you're looking for, so here goes:
The experiment in the example presents a really surprising phenomenon, that the bag appears only partially filled with three lungfuls of air when his assistant blows directly into it, but goes from empty to full with a single lungful of air when it is delivered from a small distance from the opening of the bag.
The host, Steve Spangler, is not a charlatan. He has run an entertaining and authoritative channel for over ten years, presenting and explaining all manner of interesting physics phenomena, many involving pressure, balloons, and always basing his explanations on valid, classical physics principles.
On this occasion he states that by "combining weather and science we use Bernoulli's Principle" and "using fast moving air" they fill the bag with a single breath.
I understand that Bernoulli's Principle states when an incompressible, inviscid fluid, flows through a tube,  when the tube constricts, the fluid moves faster and the pressure reduces, and when it opens up again, the flow speed reduces and the pressure increases.
I know that mathematicians after Bernoulli formalised the principle int what is now referred to as Euler's equation, that goes along the lines p + ½ ρV^2 = constant (p = pressure,  ρ=density and V = flow velocity)
The experimental data was presented: Tube 8' long, 10" around and holds 45 L of air . We can assume NTP conditions.
My question is how does that principle or that equation explain why a single breath delivered a little distance from the opening fills the tube that couldn't even be slightly filled with three full breaths?
[EDIT 2]
He seems to have got the maths wrong:
We have a cylindrical tube.
Length = 8 feet,
Diameter = 10 inches
Calculations:
Convert units:
1 foot = 12 inches
1 inch = 2.54 centimetres
1 litre = 1000 cubic centimetres
Calculate the radius:
Radius = Diameter / 2 = 10 inches / 2 = 5 inches
Calculate the volume of the cylinder:
Volume = π * radius^2 * height
Volume = 3.14159 * (5 inches * 2.54 cm/inch)^2 * (8 feet * 12
inches/foot * 2.54 cm/inch)
Volume ≈ 123,555.5 cubic centimetres
Convert to litres:
Volume = 123,555.5 cubic centimetres / 1000 = 123.56 litres (approximately)
Therefore, a tube that is 8 feet long and 10 inches in diameter can hold approximately 123.56 litres, not his estimate of 45 litres.

Similar: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759498/how-can-i-mathematically-model-the-entrainment-of-air-through-a-window

HMMM, perhaps, but there are at least two theories duking it out.  With no real answer. The Cool Science is an actual experiment rather than a thought experiment.  We can make measurements and test the answers.

Not sure Bernoulli is all that helpful. I would simply argue with momentum conservation directly.

That's interesting: The question has been up for three weeks with no answers. Is it that hard?

@FlatterMann Would you like to present an answer based on momentum conservation?

@rationalDiscourse No, not really. Continuum mechanics was my worst class. I barely made the cut. I don't have much love for it.

@FlatterMann, Pity. I wonder then, why you bothered.

@rationalDiscourse Nobody here is bothered by this question. You take a little bit of air that's fast and it collides with a lot of standing air and then you get a lot of air that is slow. That's momentum conservation. For me that's all there is to it. I don't need equations or anything to understand this intuitively. Do you?

You have an intuitive explanation, sure, but you are expressing it using technical terms:  momentum and conservation. Why aren't you willing to do the math? Please, give it a go.

m1v1=m2v2. If you try to do this for actual airflow it gets complicated really fast. I don't like complicated.

You might as well have written E=mc^2 for all the relevance it had to your answer.

It's simple.
Because air is viscous, when you blow air into a bag from a distance, due to its viscosity, the air you blow out will carry more air movement, filling the bag with one blow.
Bernoulli's law is a theory about ideal fluids without viscosity, so it cannot be used here.

I think this answer could more clearly state the point for the OP: the moving air drags surrounding air with it, pulling it into the bag. When blown directly into the object, it does not pass by adjacent air and does not have a chance to do this

But also, the person in the video invokes Bernoulli's principle claiming that the central jet of air from his mouth has a lower pressure due to its motion, which causes surrounding air to rush inward, filling the bag. This would happen even with inviscid flow.

@RC_23 The analogy of blowing air with the mouth is not strict. For example, the surface of the lips is curved, and so on. You can use a garden hose analogy. Water flows out from a garden hose, and after leaving the outlet of the garden hose, the pressure of the water is generally atmospheric pressure.

@RC_23 I'm interested in the idea that air "drags surrounding air". Do you have any literature on that (not Wiki!)
